# photoswipe: passing HTML file instead of image

Tags: photoswipe

I would like to use the same set up as Photoswipe, only pass a div or index.html through instead of an image.

Here is the link to the photoswipe package:

http://www.photoswipe.com

Please let me know if this isn't possible! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you use get method to load more images you can get html instead of images.
Just you need to print html as you require in your ajax request. And then you can display the html by using javascript i.e when you get html in your data variable.